# How to create a patterned image from existing shape in Gimp

Tags: gimp, logo

I am hoping to create a simple logo for a new website using Gimp.  I am working with two images and a short line of text.  I have the following images:
[image: This will be the background/filler of the logo]

[image: This is the final outline/shape of the logo, filled with the map pattern]

The map will be the background/filler of the logo
The sun will be the final outline/shape of the logo, filled with the map pattern.

Basically, I want the map image cut into the shape of the setting sun.  I'd like to add some text over that, and have just the sun/text combination as the logo, to be placed over a black background.  I've been reading and watching tutorials for hours...any direction would be much appreciated!  Thank you!

Comment: Are you meaning to apply a [pattern](http://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-concepts-patterns.html) after copying the map into the clipboard?

Answer (score 1):

`Filters->Map->Make Seamles`
That simple :-)

It copies your image offset by half width and height to the corners and with a transparent gradient, so that the original content is shown at the center.

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to create a patterned background, or is something like this what you're trying to do? You're wording isn't clear.

[image]

Sorry, but I don't have enough rep to post this as a comment.

[Edit] I never explained what I did because OP never answered my question. I still don't know what she actually wanted to do.

Anyway. Downloaded the two images. Placed the map on one layer and the sunrise image on a layer above it, centering it roughly over Tibet just because. Selected the blue and gray areas on the sunrise layer, then inverted the selection. Created a new layer and filled the selection with black. Deleted (or made invisible) the sunrise layer. Added some text. Flattened. That's one way.

Another would be to add a mask to the sunrise layer, select the blue and gray areas and then fill the selection with black in the mask to block out the sunrise. Go back to the image proper and delete the white, then select the entire layer and fill with black. Create type layer. Flatten.

A third would be to create a layer between the map and the sunrise, fill it with black and add a mask.  Go up to the sunrise layer, select the blue and gray areas, then back to the mask and fill the selection with black. Delete (or make invisible) the sunrise layer. Create type layer. Flatten.

Have I beaten this to death yet? This was almost 6 months ago. I don't remember exactly what I did. :-/

Comment: What if you explain the technique you used to achieve that image?